# Time Complexity and Big O Notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I am stuck on a homework question. The question is as follows.

Consider four programs - A, B, C, and D - that have the following performances.

1. A: O(log n)
2. B: O(n)
3. C: O(n<sup>2</sup>)
4. C: O(2<sup>n</sup>)

If each program requires 10 seconds to solve a problem of size 1000, estimate the time required by each program when the size of its problem increases to 2000.

I am pretty sure that O(n) would just double to 20 seconds since we are doubling the size and this would represent a loop in Java that iterates n number of times. Doubling n would double the output. But I am completely lost on numbers 1, 3, and 4.

I am not looking for direct answers to this question, but rather for someone to dumb down the way I can arrive at the answer. Maybe by explaining what each of these Big O notations is actually doing on the back end. If I understood the way that the algorithm is calculated and where all the elements fit into some sort of equation to solve for time, that would be awesome. Thank you in advance.

I have spent weeks combing through the textbook, but it is all written in a very complicated matter that I am having a hard time digesting. Videos online haven't been much help either.

Comment: Is it 2^4 in option 4?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you dumb this down you risk not understanding properly.  The maths is the key to understanding.   But if you want an intuitive understanding, draw graphs of the 4 functions on paper (or use a graphing calculator) and see what they do as N gets larger and larger.

Comment: Well, what is the ratio between *log(1000)* and *log(2000)* in case A? Similarly for the other cases.

Comment: The question you are trying to answer seems to depend on you knowing what the mathematical definition of `O` notation is actually saying.   I don't think you can avoid that.  I certainly think you shouldn't *try to* avoid that!

Comment: I am not trying to avoid it. Just hoping someone can dumb down what each big O does and how it relates to this question. I want to understand it fully, but don't want to be flooded with a bunch of technical jargon I don't understand yet. I am still learning. Only taken Programming I and Programming II in college so far. This question is from my Data Structures and Algorithms class that I am currently taking.

Comment: The class is all reading and assignments with very little interaction with the instructor. I was never really good with High School algebra, and the text book doesn't explain things that well in my opinion. There are a lot of holes, and they assume you understand most of what they are teaching before setting a good foundation. That all being said, I am pretty sure that someone who went through the struggles I have right now, found a simpler way of understanding this topic.

Comment: The simple way is to understand what *log(N)* means, and the other equations in C and D, and to compute their ratios. Too broad for this site. We've tried.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks anyway. I'll keep trying to figure it out. Have a great night. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's have an example (the one that you don't have in your list): O(n^3).
The ratio between the sizes of your problems is 2: `2000/1000 = 2`. The big-O notation gives you an estimation that if you have a problem of size `n` the complexity of the problem of the size `2n` would be... `(2n)^3 = 8n^3`. That is 8 times higher than the original task.

I hope that would help.

Comment: It gets my head floating around in the right direction, but I am failing to see how (2n)^3 = 8n^3. How do we arrive at 8?

Comment: @LeviBorland 2 to the power 3 = 8, and the rest is basic (high school)  factorization.

Comment: `8 = 2*2*2 = 2^3`. The ^ sign means the 'power'.

Comment: Duh, I understand now how we arrive at 8. Man high school was almost 10 years ago. Wish I started coding back then, instead of waiting until I am almost 30.

Comment: @LeviBorland. I've started studying bioinformatics in 35 when I disappointed in coding. Since that time I've been studying almost every day. Welcome onboard.